# Are programs able to access read-only files?

Tags: command, matlab

For example, I am accessing a computer cluster through SSH, and I am running a Matlab program to take in data and then write to a text file.

The problem is, the data is read only. So am I still able to have my program access the data and then write it to a text file in my directory?

So far there's been an error that says "Could not open file", so I'm trying to figure out what the problem is.

[image: error]

Comment: For which file does that message appear, the input one or the output one?

Comment: After the Could not open message, it is followed by the directory from which I'm trying to access the data. Here, I can attach a screenshot.

Comment: there it is the screenshot

Comment: A screenshot doesn't ease copy/paste. Anyway, check the target directory permissions (using its full path): `ls -ld /home/.../L1-CAL-DELTAL_EXTERNAL_DQ`.

Comment: copy and paste text, not screenshots.  quote it using the `{}` icon in the SE editor.

Comment: I'm not sure how to copy and paste in the terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, read-only obviously means read is possible.

Whether you'll be able to write a file in a directory is unrelated to the property of the file you read there, only the directory permissions do matter.